# Apply tranformation to particular list elements

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I have a list with elements

```
{a -> -1, b -> -2, c -> -3}
```

If I now wanted to apply a tranformation to `b` and `c` so that they would give the tranformation `b -> 1-10^val` and `c -> 1-10^val`, yielding

```
{a -> -1, b -> 0.99, c -> 0.999}
```

How would I do this in *Mathematica*?

Comment: Ha yes apologies that's what I meant I changed my question accordingly - thanks for both of your answers they work perfectly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you mean something different by `1-b^-2` or you just miscalculated, because your result is not the correct result. In general, you can transform transformation-rules like this:

```
{a -> -1, b -> -2, c -> -3} /. 
  {
    (b -> val_) :> (b -> 1 - val^-2),
    (c -> val_) :> (c -> 1 - val^-3)
  }
```

And in case Kuba is right about what you really want, then you can use

```
{a -> -1, b -> -2, c -> -3} /. 
  {
    (b -> val_) :> (b -> 1 - 10.0^val), 
    (c -> val_) :> (c -> 1 - 10.0^val)
  }
(* {a -> -1, b -> 0.99, c -> 0.999} *)
```

Or

```
{a -> -1, b -> -2, c -> -3} /. 
  {(key : b | c -> val_) :> (key -> 1 - 10.0^val)}
```

Comment: Also, val are equal to powers, which is suspicious. I suppose to formula is `1-10^val`.

Comment: Was already adding it :-)

Comment: Many thanks for this - works perfectly! 2nd solution is what I was looking for - sorry for the typo in my question!

Answer (score 5):

```
list = {a -> -1, b -> -2, c -> -3}
```

The quesiton is unclear but let's say I know what you want :)

```
MapAt[
  1. - 10^# &,
  Association[list],
  List@*Key /@ {b, c}] // Normal
```

> {a -> -1, b -> 0.99, c -> 0.999}

You could work on `Association` from the begining, then you can skip `Association[]` and `Normal` which makes it even more compact.

---

Other way, if you know positions and don't want to use `Associations`:

```
MapAt[
  1. - 10^# &,
  list,
  {2 ;; 3, 2}]
```

Comment: Many thanks for this - works perfectly!